# Do I need AppFabric locally To test Azure Co-Located Caching in develpment

Tags: azure-web-roles, appfabric-cache

I am creating a web app which uses Co-Located Cache for Session management. In development, I am getting this error

> Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the Cache administration tool to create a Cache

But I don't know from where I can create cache. I have Azure SDK installed and m using VS2012. I don't have any server with AppFabric installed. 
Do I need to install AppFabric? If yes then can someone please provide a link to install and consume AppFabric in dev mode. If no then what the solution is ?
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the **cachename** in your cache client configuration.

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" 
        type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider,
              Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" 
        cacheName="default" 
        dataCacheClientName="default"/>
    </providers>
  </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

It should be **default** or another cache created on the server.

Please refer to this [link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) for configuring Azure Co-Located Caching.